# How to upload Json Data or file in Elasticsearch using Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

This is my sample Json Data coming from .json file now I want to do bulk_insert to elasticsearch dynamically so that I can perform operations on it ..can someone help me with java code to add this data dynamically ..this is just a piece of 5-6objects like this i have more then 500objects

```
[{

"data1" : "developer",
"data2" : "categorypos",
"data3" : "1001"
},
{

"data1" : "developer",
"data1" : "developerpos",
"data1" : "1002"
},
{

"data1" : "developer",
"data2" : "developpos",
"data3" : "1003"
},
{

"data1" : "support",
"data2" : "datapos",
"data3" : "1004"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a provision of bulk operations in elastic search following is the documentation this might help
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: before posting it here I have undergone this documentation but didnt got my answer or may be I am not be able to understand it

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file from your application, iterate over the array and for each document, send it to elasticsearch.

To do the latest, you should use the bulk processor class.

```
    BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(
            (request, bulkListener) -> esClient.bulkAsync(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, bulkListener),
            new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void beforeBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request) { }
                @Override
                public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, BulkResponse response) { }
                @Override
                public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) { }
            })
            .setBulkActions(10000)
            .setFlushInterval(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(5))
            .build();
```

For each `json` document, call:

```
bulkProcessor.add(new IndexRequest("INDEXNAME").source(json, XContentType.JSON));
```

Comment: sorry , It doesnt helped me out , looking for more simplified solution